# Can't select cell in UITableView after bouncing scroll

Tags: ios, uikit

I am experiencing strange behaviour in multiple `UITableViews` I have in my app.
In multiple view controllers, I can cause the `UITableViewCells` to stop being selectable by performing the following action :

1 - Scroll the table view downward with a strong swipe-up, passing the bottom of the table, triggering the bounce effect

2 - While the table view is "recovering" from the bounce and moving upward, click the bottom of the table view (where no cell is currently present due to the bounce)

If this action is repeated, once in a few tries the bounce will stop midway. During this state, the `UITableViewCells` are unselectable by tapping on them.
To recover from this state, a slight scroll needs to be performed. This will cause the bounce to finish its recovery, the `UITableView` will return to a sane state and cells will be selectable again.

Has anyone encountered this? Is it solvable? (Using latest iOS 7 version, testing on iPad mini retina)

Comment: not clear about your problem, can you update question and give us a try

Comment: I can't really find a way to explain it differently. I explained a usage scenario that causes the UITableView to stop functioning correctly across multiple instances in my app, and there is no shared code.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.. did you got a solution for it?

Comment: same for me too :O my tableview is super simple...i only have 1 label in my cell @__@